# Multiple Select with multiple where clauses and Groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the data from the mysql database for generating report.but I am struggling when I have multiple selects with multiple where and group clauses.

what I want to do is I want `SUM(pf.meter)` in the second and third select statements should return the values according to the where clause is given in relevant select statement and needs to group by main select statements Group by clause.

[image]
please find the attachemnet.in there not planned qty is same for all the rows it cannot be like that.it should be group by customer, color, style.

Here is my **SQL**

```
SELECT  pm.date, 
        pm.customer, 
        pf.style, 
        pf.color, 
        COUNT(pf.roll_no) AS Roll_QTY,
        SUM(pf.yard) AS Yard_QTY, 
        SUM(pf.meter) AS Meter_QTY, 
        SUM(pf.kilo) AS Kilo_QTY, 
        (
            SELECT SUM(pf.meter)
            FROM packinglists_fabrics_items pf, packinglists_main pm
            WHERE pf.aql_status = 0
            AND pf.grn_no= pm.gp_no[
            AND pm.date BETWEEN {DateR, RANGE1} AND {DateR, RANGE2}]
        ) FB_Not_Passed_Qty,    
        (
            SELECT SUM(pf.meter)
            FROM packinglists_fabrics_items pf, packinglists_main pm
            WHERE pf.aql_status = 1
            AND pf.tag_gen = 0
            AND pf.grn_no= pm.gp_no[
            AND pm.date BETWEEN {DateR, RANGE1} AND {DateR, RANGE2}]
        ) Not_Planned_Qty
FROM packinglists_main pm, packinglists_fabrics_items pf
WHERE pf.grn_no= pm.gp_no[
AND pm.date BETWEEN {DateR, RANGE1} AND {DateR, RANGE2}]
GROUP BY pm.customer, pf.style, pf.color
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Can you include your schema, sample data and expected output?

Comment: @shmosel i have add ab image with a description.please have a look

Comment: Please note that MySql is not Sql server. those are 2 different products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pm.date, pm.customer, pf.style, pf.color, COUNT(pf.roll_no) AS Roll_QTY,
       SUM(pf.yard) AS Yard_QTY, SUM(pf.meter) AS Meter_QTY, SUM(pf.kilo) AS Kilo_QTY, 
    SUM( case when pf.aql_status = 0  then pf.meter else 0 end ) FB_Not_Passed_Qty,
    SUM( case when pf.aql_status = 1 and  pf.tag_gen = 0  then pf.meter else 0 end ) Not_Planned_Qty
FROM packinglists_main pm,
     packinglists_fabrics_items pf
WHERE pf.grn_no= pm.gp_no[
  AND pm.date BETWEEN {DateR,
                       RANGE1} AND {DateR,
                                    RANGE2}]
GROUP BY pm.customer, pf.style, pf.color
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve; there isn't any sample data or example of expected output.

But it looks like you might be after the result of conditional aggregation:

The result from something like this:

```
SELECT pm.date
     , pm.customer
     , pf.style
     , pf.color
     , COUNT(pf.roll_no)    AS Roll_QTY
     , SUM(pf.yard)         AS Yard_QTY
     , SUM(pf.meter)        AS Meter_QTY
     , SUM(pf.kilo)         AS Kilo_QTY

     , SUM( IF(pf.aql_status = 0, pf.meter, 0) ) AS FB_Not_Passed_Qty

     , SUM( IF(pf.aql_status = 1 AND pf.tag_gen = 0, pf.meter, 0) ) AS Not_Planned_Qty

  FROM packinglists_main pm
  JOIN packinglists_fabrics_items pf
    ON pf.grn_no = pm.gp_no
 WHERE pm.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
 GROUP
    BY pm.customer
     , pf.style
     , pf.color
```

Some suggestions:

Ditch the old-school comma operator for join operations, and use the newer JOIN syntax with the join predicates in the ON clause.